# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)' - Swift Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Getting this error trying to convert to a double. Any ideas why?

```
 class ViewController : UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var textField : UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var answerButton : UIButton!
        @IBOutlet var fahrenheitLabel : UILabel!

        @IBAction func tempFieldEditingChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            fahrenheitLabel.text = textField.text

        }
        @IBAction func showAnswer (_ sender : UIButton) {
        let temperatures = ["hot","warm","cool","cold"]
        let thresholds : [Double] = [80,60,40,0]

        let temperature = Double(textField.text)   //<-- (ERROR)

        for (i,threshold) in thresholds.enumerated() {
             if temperature >= threshold {
                 fahrenheitLabel.text = temperatures[i]
                 break
                }
             }
         }
   }
```

Trying to take user input of a temperature and spit out a label with hot warm cool or cold. I know theres something I'm missing please help! Thank you.

Comment: As the error says, `textField.text` is an optional `String?`.  You need to unwrap `textField.text` before you can use it to create a Double.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textField.text` is an *optional String*, so you need to unwrap it before passing the value to a function that doesn’t accept an optional, such as the `Double(_ String:)` initialiser.

I would use a `guard` statement to do so. The string may not be able to be parsed as a Double, so that initialiser also returns an optional, which needs to be unwrapped.

```
@IBAction func showAnswer (_ sender : UIButton) {
    guard let text = textField.text else {
        return
    }
    let temperatures = ["hot","warm","cool","cold"]
    let thresholds : [Double] = [80,60,40,0]

    if let temperature = Double(text) {

        for (i,threshold) in thresholds.enumerated() {
             if temperature >= threshold {
                 fahrenheitLabel.text = temperatures[i]
                 break
                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But one more issue getting another error here. Getting "Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Double'" at         (` if temperature >= threshold {`)

Comment: You rock. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The `UITextField.text` property returns an optional `String?` type. The `Double`'s initializer requires a regular `String`.

To use the `text` property, you must first "unwrap" it, i.e. transform it from an optional value into a non-optional. There are several ways to do it:

### Forced unwrapping

If you are certain, that the text property is not nil, you may forcibly unwrap it. Be mindful though, as when you try to forcibly unwrap a nil value, your app will crash.

```
if textField.text != nil {
    let temperature = Double(textField.text!)
}
```

In this case, the `text` property should never be nil. However, if there were some code changing the property inside the `if` statement and before the line where the property is forcibly unwrapped, the forced uwrapping might crash.

### Optional binding (the preferred way)

This method lets you unwrap the property *safely* by binding its value to another constant/variable, and once the value is bound, it can be freely used without the possibility of it becoming nil.

```
if let temperatureValue = textField.text {
    let temperature = Double(temperatureValue)
}
```

The unwrapped `temperatureValue` constant will remain available and non-optional throughout the whole if-let scope, meaning that up to the closing brace of the if-let statement you can use it freely and will be gone outside the statement's braces. If the `textField.text` is nil, the inside of the statement's braces will never be executed.

Instead of `if-let`, you might use the `guard-let` statement:

```
guard let temperatureValue = textField.text else {
    return
}

let temperature = Double(temperatureValue)
```

Notice however that any `guard` statement requires the function to return if the statement fails, but the unwrapped value can be accessed normally in the rest of the function, not only in a closing braces of a statement, like with `if-let`.

Last thing: the `Double`'s initializer that takes a `String` also returns an optional value - so in order to use it (e.g. compare to other `Double` values), you must unwrap it as well:

```
if let temperature = Double(temperatureValue) {
    // compare "temperature" to other Double values
}
```

Comment: Don't even teach the `!= nil` approach. Optional binding is most certainly the way to go.

Comment: I know it's not the safe way to do it, but even the Swift Programming Language tells about forced unwrapping and I'd rather see the `!= nil` safeguard than none at all. But I agree, optional binding is almost always the proper way.

Comment: Yeah, but I've found that when beginners are presented so many options, it's necessarily confusing, and can become unclear which form to use. It's good to eventually learn the underpinnings (e.g. exactly what conditional binding really does), but I would avoid presenting it up-front like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with `if let` way

```
let atextField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
atextField.text = "55.9"
if let d = Double(atextField.text!) {
    print(d)
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap `.text`. Here is how I would do it:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var answerButton : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var fahrenheitLabel : UILabel!

    @IBAction func tempFieldEditingChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        fahrenheitLabel.text = textField.text
    }

    @IBAction func showAnswer (_ sender : UIButton) {

        guard let text = textField else {
            fatalError("Handle case when textField.text is nil") // TODO
        }
        guard let temperature = Double(textField) {
            fatalError("Handle case when textField.text is nonnil but not a double") // TODO
        }

        switch temperature {
            case ..<40: textField.text = "cold"
            case 40..<60: textField.text = "cool"
            case 60..<80: textField.text = "warm"
            case 80...: textField.text = "hot"
            default: fatalError("Non-exhaustive temperature ranges!")
        }
    }
}
```